# TabBarController within the RootViewController of a SplitViewController

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I'd like to develop an iPad app which would be composed of a `SplitViewController`. I'd like to add a `TabBarController` in the RootViewController.

I'm at the very beginning of the development. So I've started to simply create a new project, add a `SplitViewController` via `Interface Builder` and test the app, no problem of course. Then I've tried to add the `TabBarController` to the RootView, no problem either via the `Interface Builder`. The problem I have there is that I can't make the app rotate with the device. I assume that I have to change something in the code but I don't know what :-(
I've noticed that the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is never called when the device rotates.
I'm sorry to ask this question but I'm very new in developping iPad/iPhone apps.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:annualViewController];
[navigationController1.navigationBar addSubview:imageView1];
[list addObject:navigationController1];
[imageView1 release];

UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation bar.png"]];
imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
[navigationController2.navigationBar addSubview:imageView2];
[list addObject:navigationController2];
[imageView2 release];

tabBarController.viewControllers=list;

detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
rootViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
annualViewController.detailViewController=detailViewController;

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabBarController, detailViewController, nil];
splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

// Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.

[window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```