# How to add tab bar controllers to the root view of the split view controller application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

[image]

I am very new to the iPad `UISplitViewController`.

I need to add a tab bar containing 3 tabs at the bottom of the master view / left view. I have a different View Controller for each of the 3 tabs. I haven't found any other examples of Tab bars being used in split view based applications.

Where do I insert a tab bar controller for displaying at the bottom of the the root view?

How do I establish a connection so that when I select a table cell, the detailItem info gets displayed in the Detail View? Tab bar was added to the Root View in IB. Should I be adding it programmatically instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573452/tabbarcontroller-within-the-rootviewcontroller-of-a-splitviewcontroller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952214/tabbarcontroller-and-splitviewcontroller might help

Comment: oh i thought you wanted for the whole app. but basically its the same idea. you can put your views in tabcontroller and then use the tabcontroller in your master controlle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to take UITabBarController dynaically.

In .h file

**UITabBarController *tabBar;**

in .m file

create objects to your classes in appDidFinish Launch

For example you have

Class1 and Class2

**in appDidFinishLaunch**

**Class1 *obj1=[Class1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:nil];**
**Class2 *obj2=[Class2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Class2" bundle:nil];**

// Master navigation controller by defaults comes with template code

// Now you have create Array for tabBar

**NSArray *tabViewArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1,obj2,masterNavigationController,  nil];**

**tabBar=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];**

**[tabBar setViewControllers:tabViewArray];**

// now you have to edit the statement which contains splitview.viewArray repalce masterNavigataionControler with tabBar

**self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabBar, detailNavigationController, nil];**

Try this i hope it will helps you.

Comment: YesThis is what i want... tabbar instead of masterNavigationController

Answer (score 3):

in your app delegate add tabbar controller then add your view controllers to tabbar controller and set the window rootview controller to tabbar controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
 self.tabbar=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   self.vc1 = [[vc1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   // do the same to other VCs
    self.tabbar.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4, nil];


self.window.rootViewController = self.tabbar;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

i hope it helps :-)

Comment: oh i thought you wanted for the whole app. but basically its the same idea. you can put your views in tabcontroller and then use the tabcontroller in your master controller

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is initialize the first argument of uispliviewcontroller for view as tabbar instead of a view or you can use uisegmentedcontrol.