# How to add tab bar controller to the detail view of a split view controller application

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'm working on a catalog application for iPad/iPhone devices. I'm, using the master view template from XCode to have a base, in the root or master navigation controller I'm showing the list of the products and now I'm trying to add a tab controller to the detail view because each product have 3 different sections, one with some details, other with a specifications table and other with some pictures or images of the product.

I'm doing this programmatically, this is my code of AppDelegate.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import "MVADetailVwCtrl.h"
    #import "MVATableVwCtrl.h"
    #import "MVAModelVwCtrl.h"

    @interface MVAAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *rootTabBarCtrl;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) MVADetailVwCtrl *detailVwCtrl;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) MVATableVwCtrl *tableVwCtrl;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) MVAModelVwCtrl *modelVwCtrl;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* viewControllers;

    @end
```

And this is the code on AppDelegate.m

```
    #import "MVAAppDelegate.h"

    @implementation MVAAppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.detailVwCtrl = [[MVADetailVwCtrl alloc] init];
        // self.newMoveVwCtrl.title = @"Product details";
        UINavigationController *detailNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.detailVwCtrl];

        self.tableVwCtrl = [[MVATableVwCtrl alloc] init];
        // self.myAccountsVwCtrl.title = @"Table";
        UINavigationController *tableNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tableVwCtrl];

        self.modelVwCtrl = [[MVAModelVwCtrl alloc] init];
        // self.settingsVwCtrl.title = @"Pictures";
        UINavigationController *modelNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.modelVwCtrl];

        self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                detailNavCtrl,
                                tableNavCtrl,
                                modelNavCtrl,
                                nil];

        self.rootTabBarCtrl = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        self.rootTabBarCtrl.viewControllers = self.viewControllers;

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
            splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
        }

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.rootTabBarCtrl, [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject], nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromHex(0x009B3E)];

        return YES;
    }
```

I'm creating each tab and each navigation controller of each tab and storing all of them in an array, and then I'm retrieving the view controllers of the split view to change them with the new ones but I don't know if this is the best approaching.

Maybe there is a best method editing the storyboard, and I would like to keep the compatibility of the application with iPad and iPhone devices.

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I follow some recommendations from this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493711/how-to-add-tab-bar-controllers-to-the-root-view-of-the-split-view-controller-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493711/how-to-add-tab-bar-controllers-to-the-root-view-of-the-split-view-controller-app) but I want the tab controller on the detail view, not in the master view.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order of the view controllers in your split view, which will switch detail and master view.

```
  splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [splitViewController.viewControllers firstObject], self.rootTabBarCtrl, nil];`
```

Comment: I switch the order of the view controllers, now the application starts with the detail view first instead the master view, and the detail view is in blank without the tabs. I think I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying doing everything programmatically instead using the XCode template.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, it should be `firstObbject`, not `lastObject`. Now the master view should be first. 
But I don't know why the tab bar does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted won't run on iPhone since `UISplitViewController` is only supported on iPad. 
Have you considered to use Storyboards instead of doing this programatically? I think in your case this could make things a lot easier. In this [Stanford course](https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/593208016/feed) the teacher explains how to make an iPhone app using storyboard universal and he also uses a split view controller.

Comment: Hello @HackingOtter, the application is actually an universal app and runs on iPhone an iPad. In my first try I started it using the Master-Detail template but now I did everything programmatically. Now I threw away the tabs and I'm using UISegmentedControls in the DetailView that is a better approaching. I don't like storyboards :( , maybe because I don't understand them, but I'm considering using them from future projects.