# Swift: Split view controller on universal app that isnt initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a universal app and want to add a split view controller for my settings view only. This means that I require a split view controller that isnt the initial view controller which would handle the interaction between SettingMainTableViewController (the main settings page) and SettingDetailViewController (showing the individual settings). All the guides and tutorials I can see online assume that the split view controller is the initial view controller.

The flow would be MainMenuViewController -> SettingMainTableViewController -> SettingDetailViewController which would be displayed as a split if on ipad and not split if iphone. Is this possible to achieve and how would I go about it?

[image: current setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without setting it as `rootViewController`, you can use it in the same way you use other `UIViewController`s. You can present in modally or even push it to navigation stack. One of the example is as given below:

```
let rootViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let navVC: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

let detailViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let splitVC: UISplitViewController = UISplitViewController()
splitVC.viewControllers = [navVC, detailViewController]
self.present(splitVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I add this code in viewDidAppear then it only shows the red background view controller if the device is an ipad and the blue view controller if the device is an iphone but never presents them both as a split view.

Comment: @R.Ham , I will get back to you in few minutes on this

Comment: @R.Ham, to get this behave like a splitViewController in storyboard, there are a few modifications that need to be done. I will improve my edit to answer them

Comment: @R.Ham, A `SplitViewController` has a `rootViewController` and `detailViewcontroller`. It's initial behaviour from storyboard is maintained by the code. You can check my latest edit.

Comment: It still only shows the red background view controller if the device is an ipad and the blue view controller if the device is an iphone .

Comment: @R.Ham, Take the iPad to landscape mode or swipe at the left side to view the rootviewcontroller. That's the functionality of `SplitViewController`. Can you give me the tutorial link that you have so that I can accordingly modify my code to match that

Comment: All the tutorials do it via the storyboard, but they assume the split view controller is the initial view controller. I thought a split view controller automatically loaded the second view controller (detail) on the right hand side of the screen. Is there any way to make it work like this programmatically?

Comment: like the image seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493711/how-to-add-tab-bar-controllers-to-the-root-view-of-the-split-view-controller-app

Comment: @R.Ham, That's in landscape mode. Not in portrait mode. My latest code behaves like that

Comment: Yes same for me, is there a way to make it work the same in portrait as well? (thanks for your help by the way!)

Comment: That's the way 'SplitViewController' works. In portrait mode, you have to swipe to access the other view controller. If that's the functionality you want, you are looking for something else.

Comment: Not true.. after some research the following code makes it work in portrait: splitVC.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible. Thanks for your help

Comment: @R.Ham Great to know. Good luck for your project.

Comment: @KrishnaCA have you try to push with splitVC

Answer (score 0):

The technique I prefer is using a "container view controller" (google it) as the root view controller. That view controller transitions between your normal app view controller hierarchy and the settings split view controller. You can use a variety of transitions to switch from one to the other. A nice attribute of this solution is that you only dedicate memory for Settings when its run - once switched out, that view controller can be released.

EDIT: You have a root container view. On startup you just show view A (VC-A) immediately. Later on, you decide to show view B (VC-B). You create a transition, go from A to B, then at the very end, you release view controller VC-A. Matt Neuburg has great treatment in his iOS books- that's where I got the technique from. Sure that this is also covered elsewhere. What is interesting is that the root container view can ALSO show some UI in its view! Does get a bit complex then, but I've done it.

Comment: I use container views in my app currently. Could you explain a bit further or provide some sample code on how this works? Thanks

Comment: @David H Hello. Which Matt Neuburg did you see this treatment in?

Comment: @LanceSamaria https://www.amazon.com/Programming-iOS-10-Controllers-Frameworks/dp/1491970162/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1494728041&sr=8-1&keywords=matt+neuburg

Comment: @David H Thanks! :)